# Trouble with adding information to JSON library in Python

Tags: python, json, loops, logic

So I have been trying to build out a dynamic JSON library with python recently, and I'm having problems with looping through data. This problem is likely an easy fix but I am very new to programming and especially new to working with JSON.

Basically, I am trying to come out with a JSON output that looks similar to this:

```
    {
      "src_host": [
        "list item 1",
        [
          "SSH",
          "Telnet",
          "STMP"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "src_host": [
        "list item 2",
        [
          "SSH",
          "Telnet",
          "STMP"
        ]
      ]
    }
```

I want to populate every "src_host" list with a single entry from another list. I basically want to have a src_host defined for every list item that is being provided. The code I am using is as shown below:

```
host_dict = {}
host_dict["src_host"] = []
host_services_list = ["SSH","Telnet","STMP"]

mylist = ["list item 1", "list item 2"]

counter = 0

for item in mylist:
    json_data['zone'][0]['hosts'].append(host_dict)
    host_dict['src_host'].append(mylist[counter])
    counter = counter + 1

host_dict['src_host'].append(host_services_list)
```

The issue I am running into seems to be with the loop I have made to populate the Json data. For a reason I cannot figure out, when I execute this code, the Json output comes out like so:

```
    {
      "src_host": [
        "list item 1",
        "list item 2",
        [
          "SSH",
          "Telnet",
          "STMP"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "src_host": [
        "list item 1",
        "list item 2",
        [
          "SSH",
          "Telnet",
          "STMP"
        ]
      ]
    }
```

As you can see, the list items "list item 1" and "list item 2" are appended to each src_host list, rather than "list item 1" being added to the first src_host and "list item 2" being added to the second.

I'm assuming my logic is flawed here or I'm missing something super simple, but I can't seem to get past this one problem at the moment and wanted to reach out for assistance.

Thank you for any and all help!

**Note:** The ['zone'][0]['hosts'] is because this portion of Json is a small piece in a larger Json file. I didn't think it was necessary to show every bit of the Json file but wanted to still explain just in case.

Comment: Do you really want all your nested information to be lists? I would use a dictionary for those nested items so you dont have to do all the `[0]` if there are going to be one item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this data structure will do you any favors but here is a super simple list comprehension to get it done:

```py
host_title = 'src_host'
host_services_list = ['SSH', 'Telnet', 'STMP']
mylist = ['list item 1', 'list item 2']

hosts = [{host_title: [item, host_services_list]}
         for item in mylist]

import json
print(json.dumps(hosts, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "src_host": [
      "list item 1",
      [
        "SSH",
        "Telnet",
        "STMP"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "src_host": [
      "list item 2",
      [
        "SSH",
        "Telnet",
        "STMP"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

The key here is starting with `mylist` and building out the data from there, this may not work depending on the structure of the rest of your data though.

Comment: This was actually exactly what I was hoping for. With some light modifications I was able to use this structure in my code and it worked very well. Thank you so much for the great answer! I would openly upvote your answer but my reputation is too low at the moment!